# Redirect to dynamic route with regex on NextJS config file

Tags: next.js, dynamic-routing

My problem is that I'm building a new site, and in my old one there was some pages with a child route /feed.

For example: *[www.mypage.com/blogs/blog-1/feed](http://www.mypage.com/blogs/blog-1/feed)*

So, what I'm trying to do is to redirect from */blogs/blog-1/feed* to */blogs/blog-1*, but now it shows me an 404 error.

These blog pages are dynamic, they are inside a [slug].tsx file, so what I've tried was to made an [...slug].tsx file, but because I'm using getStaticPaths and getStaticProps methods, it doesn't works (Or I don't know how to do it properly).

So, my other option, and the one that I think is the most appropriate, it's to add some kind of redirect regex expression on next.config.js:

```
  {
    source: '/blogs/:slug(/\feed/)',
    destination: '/blogs/:slug',
    permanent: true,
  },
```

Am I right, or is there a better way to do this? Because obviously the code I have put in does not work, I am not telling to the config file how to remove that '/feed' fragment from the :slug.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try updating the `source` to `'/blogs/:slug/feed/'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the first part of your route was different between old and new sites, you'd want the wildcard path matching options in `next.config.js` which is currently documented [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/redirects#wildcard-path-matching)

To quote the docs:

> To match a wildcard path you can use `*` after a parameter, for example `/blog/:slug*` will match `/blog/a/b/c/d/hello-world`

However your old and new routes begin the same, `/blogs`, so a redirect in your `next.config.js` doesn't seem necessary to me.

You should use the `[...slug].tsx` syntax in the actual name of your file to match whatever comes after `/blogs` - this is documented [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-segments)

Your page should be at `/pages/blogs/[...slug].tsx` in this case. This will match a request for `/blogs/blog-1` or `/blogs/blog-1/feed`, and provide `["blog-1"]` or `["blog-1","feed"]` as the `slug` parameter in your `getStaticProps` - in javascript rather than typescript as follows:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params: { slug } }) {
  // do stuff
  return {
    props: {
      foo: "bar",
    }
  };
}
```

This will pass a property `foo` with a value of the string `bar` to your main page function:

```
export default function Blog({foo}) {
  return (<>{foo}</>);
}
// output is just the string bar.
```

**Note** that using the `[...slug].tsx` syntax will result in an array (`["blog-1"]`) being passed to your page, whereas `[slug].tsx` will pass a string (`"blog-1"`).

It doesn't sound like it, but you might also want to look at [optional catch-all segments](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-segments) which look like `[[...slug]].tsx`.